# Change text-content on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with an image as a background image.

On the image I have a `h2` element in the top left corner.

What I'm trying to do is when I hover over the `div` I want the `h2` in the top left corner to disappear and a new `h2` with different text should appear in the middle of the `div`.

I could figure out the positioning myself but I just wonder how do I do the display/show of these headings based on hover?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely **don't need JS** for such a simple task.

It can all be done using CSS `:hover` on the box parent:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: #0bf;
}
.title1,
.title2 {
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.title2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* HIDE SECOND TITLE */
  opacity: 0;
}

/* WHEN BOX IS HOVERED SWAP TITLES */
.box:hover .title1 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.box:hover .title2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2 class="title1">Some title 1</h2>
  <h2 class="title2">THIS IS COOL</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Pure CSS solution:*

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100x100') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "Hello";
}

div:hover:after {
  content: "World!";
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```